# Why is my program for calculating an average getting a NaN error?

Tags: java, arrays

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Experiment {
public static void main(String args[]){
   double temps[] = {27.5,34.4};
   int k = 0;
   double total = 0;
   double avgTemp;
   while(temps.length < k)
   {
       k++;
      total += temps[0];
      System.out.println("Temp: " + temps[0]);
      temps[0] = temps[0 + 1];
    }
       avgTemp = total / k;
      System.out.println("Average: " + avgTemp);
   }// end file
  }// end class
```

> This code is everything, so if I'm missing something please let me know. I tried putting the + 1 on the outside of the temps[] array inside the while loop, and I tried to establish the variables in the while loop as well, which didn't help the NaN problem.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of this condition  `while(temps.length < k)` while loop will never execute as `temps.length` will always greater than k i.e 0.

At the end it will divide

```
avgTemp = total / k;

avgTemp = 0/0;
```

Comment: Thank you Nidhi257. I realized I needed to reverse k and avgTemp.